# Can I put chemicals in before the filter?

Tags: aquarium, water-parameters

I'm restarting my tank. It's been down for a year. I have all the chemicals and such to get it started, but haven't bought new filters.

Is it safe to go ahead and de-chlorinate the water and take other steps before getting my filter going?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can although you probably need a filter to house beneficial bacteria.

Keep in mind that if you have something like FilterStart or something that claims to get your bacteria started, it won't work if it's more than 3 months old.